# Python Get Result of Numpy Equal In Same Line

Tags: python, numpy

I'm sure there is a function for this but I can't find it.

I am doing a calculation like below:

```
# L = large iterator of lots of numpy arrays
def replace_error_nan(data):
    data[data == ERROR_VALUE] = np.nan
    return data
L = (replace_error_nan(l) for l in L)
```

I want to perform all of the operations done by replace_error_nan without needing to use the function. I'm sure this is something super simple.

Thanks!

---

**Question has been answered by someone who left a "small" comment. I made an answer to myself. Thanks!**

Comment: I don't think so... I need something to replace the values then return the array. I don't see how that would work with np.where

Comment: Oh wait, I think that will work!

Comment: Yep, that was the ticket! Thanks!

Comment: oh, sorry, I deleted my comment and now it looks like you're talking to yourself  :o)

Comment: I did a rollback, as I couldn't even read the question and upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with:

```
for l in L:
  l[l == ERROR_VALUE] = np.nan
```

If you insist on one-linering it, you can use `__setitem__` in a comprehension.  But don't.

Comment: There is because my data is very large and is an iterator.

Comment: it is an itertools.chain to be precise.

Answer (score 2):

**ANSWER**

```
L = (where(l!=ERROR_VALUE, l, np.nan) for l in L)
```

Comment: +1, however `np.where` also works for two dimensional arrays, so you could use a two dimensional instead of a list.

Comment: `where` return a new array, while your function in the question returns the array itself.

Comment: That is a good point. However, I think in this case (and actually most cases) using "where" is faster. In my experience, compressing numpy or python operations is always faster than using any python code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.place()`:

```
L = (np.place(l, l==ERROR_VALUE, np.nan) or l for l in L)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do an *iterator* operation, so that @wim's approach is no good because it means your iterator is no longer lazy, I think your approach is perfectly reasonable. Defining small functions is not the worst thing.

That said, I think these alternatives should work, though I'm on a tablet and haven't tested them:

```
L = (l for l in L if not l.__setitem__(l == ERROR_VALUE, np.nan))
```

and

```
L = (l.__setitem__(l == ERROR_VALUE, np.nan) or l for l in L)
```

They're cute (relying on `__setitem__` returning `None`), but I'd still probably go with your original approach in actual code.

---

Update, since you posted a solution with `np.where` at the same time as mine: that's probably the best solution, though it does make a copy that these ones don't. Leaving this because I kind of like the cuteness, though.